# parallelization works only with one kernel

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization

I am using MMA 12.3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04, and my license support parallelization. The default kernel is *Local* and I create another one named *newKernel*. when I launch MMA and choose *Local* to perform some calculation with parallelization it is working fine. Now if I open new notebook and choose *newKernal* to do different calculation that also includes parallelization I get this error.

```
"Unable to communicate with closed link \
LinkObject[\!\(\"/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.3/Executables/\
wolfram -noinit -subkernel -pacletreadonly -wstp\"\),125,4]"
```

Note that If I restart MMA and run the first code with *newKernal* it is working fine, but when I run the second code on *Local* I get the same error.

I tried to uninstall MMA and reinstall again and restart my computer but could not get rid of this. any help please?

For a minimal example one can use any simple code with `ParallelSum`

Comment: Did you try the standard way like `ParallelDo`, `ParalleTry` etc without manual kernel creation?

Comment: How would that help? and I need tow kernels to do different calculations separately

Comment: If separately, then try `LaunchKernels[]` and `ParallelEvaluate[cmd, kernID]`. It allows autoconfiguration of sub-kernels.

Comment: the problem is that when I `LaunchKernels[]` in the second notebook it gives the same error mentioned in the question

Comment: Forget about manually created kernel. Launch the default `Local` as master, then launch the needed amount of sub-kernels by `LaunchKernels` and use the `ParallelEvaluate[command, {kernIDs}]` in different notebooks just changing the kernID. They will work fully separately if you set the `DistributedContexts->None`.